# Cómo pasar un dato de un JTable a un JComboBox

Tags: java, eclipse

Cuando hago doble click a una fila de un `Jtable` se abre un `JDialog` en ese `Jdialog` contiene un `JComboBox` que es llenado por base de datos, cuando quiero pasar una celda de una fila a ese `JComboBox`, me abre el `JDialog` pero el dato no se muestra en `JComboBox`. Cómo haría para poder pasar ese datos al `JComboBox`.

Código cuando hago doble click al `Jtable`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void tbSerieDocumentalMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int fila = tbSerieDocumental.getSelectedRow();
        if(e.getClickCount() == 2){
            dConfigurarControlDoc cc = new dConfigurarControlDoc();
            cc.cboCentroCosto.addItem(tbSerieDocumental.getValueAt(fila,1).toString());
            cc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            cc.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Clase de `JComboBox`:

```
package Componente;

public class ComboBox {
    private String codigo;
    private String nombre;

    public ComboBox(String codigo, String nombre){
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public ComboBox() {}

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

Clase para CargarComboBox:

```
package Componente;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import Util.SqlConexion;

public class CargarComboBox {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    static DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCombo;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void cargar(JComboBox cb, String sql){
        try {
            Connection con = new SqlConexion().getConectar();
            Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) st.executeQuery(sql);
            modeloCombo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            modeloCombo.addElement(new ComboBox("0","Seleccione"));
            cb.setModel(modeloCombo);
            while(rs.next()){//recorremos la tabla
                //Agregamos al combo los valores
                modeloCombo.addElement(new ComboBox(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
            }
            rs.close();//Cerramos el recorrido
            con.close();//Cerramos la conexion
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("no hay conexión" + "" + e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static String getCodigo(JComboBox cb)//Metodo para Obtener el id
    {
        ComboBox c = (ComboBox)cb.getSelectedItem();//Seleccionamos
        String id = c.getCodigo();//Obtenemos el id
        //System.out.println(id);
        return String.valueOf(id);//Retornamos el codigo
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static String getNombre (JComboBox cb)//Metodo para Obtener el id
    {
        ComboBox c = (ComboBox)cb.getSelectedItem();//Seleccionamos
        String nombre = c.getNombre();//Obtenemos el id
        //System.out.println(id);
        return String.valueOf(nombre);//Retornamos el codigo
    }
}
```

Codigo para poner la informacion en el `JComboBox`:

```
void cargarComboBox(){
        CargarComboBox.cargar(cboCentroCosto, "Select c_ccosto, x_ccosto from fccosto");
    }
```